# Taking a list of strings and checking a separate text file to count the amount of times they appear

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm trying to count the number of times the strings from a .txt file:

Apple
Banana
Cherry
Orange

Appear individually in another .txt file, let's say a cookery book. In order to keep track of the amount of times the above 4 have appeared in the book, I have turned the book into an array of strings and would like to turn the fruit into objects with a count key and value, map over the array and then increase the value accordingly.

I'm struggling think of how to convert the four fruits into objects, and just generally if my plan is the best way to go about it?

Should say i'm using readFile from node.js.

Thanks

Comment: *convert the four fruits into objects* huh? to what end? what has the title of the question to do with the rest of it? something about an `r` you say?

Comment: Apologies i thought i changed the title not a good start. I'm essentially trying to check one text file for the 4 strings shown above. I then need to be able to sort them from most mentioned to least, therefore I need a count of each individually and thought an object would be best? The title of the post is another issue that I will try and resolve myself.

Comment: so change the title, don't talk about it :p

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you explained in your comment, I would do something like this:

```js
var text_file = "Cherry, the quick brown apple, jumped over the Orange, the lazy banana.";
var ingredient_file = "apple banana cherry orange";

var strings = {};
for (var ingredient of ingredient_file.split(" ")) {
    strings[ingredient] = 0;
}

for (var key in strings) { // loop through all possible words
    strings[key] += text_file.split(key).length - 1; // find how many times they occur
}
```

Now, this may not be exactly what you want. Maybe you want "Apple" as well as "apple" and "APPLE" to count? In that case, you could do `text_file.toLowerCase()` before counting occurences.

Maybe you want to only count the word "apple" on its own and not words that may be composed of it, such as "applecider"? In that, you may want to add a few more rules.

Hope this helped, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! The txt file containing the ingredients is incredibly long, is there a way i can take the strings out of the txt file and turn it into what you have entered on your second line above, without manually typing it out?